# PHPBB Using Custom Field External

Tags: php

Basically I'm using phpbb as a forum of the main site and for images there are captions and in the Control Panel of the forum I added a custom profile field asking if the user if he/she wants amusing or descriptive captions.

The below is something i came up with, but it is horrible, i know, and I'm stuck.

The default captions should be descriptive, so

```
if ($user->data['is_registered']){
include_once($phpbb_root_path . 'includes/functions_profile_fields.' . $phpEx);
$user->get_profile_fields( $user->data['user_id'] );
$user->profile_fields['pf_captions'];
if (pf_captions_value == descriptive)
echo "Lassoed, Hogtied, and Captured...";
else {
echo "Not your typical $18...";
}
}
```

There is also code for connecting to phpbb so ask me if you want it.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you acualy have "desciptive", as what is in the database still will work

```
if ($user->data['is_registered']){
include_once($phpbb_root_path . 'includes/functions_profile_fields.' . $phpEx);
$user->get_profile_fields( $user->data['user_id'] );
if ($user->profile_fields['pf_captions']== 'descriptive')
echo "Lassoed, Hogtied, and Captured...";
else {
echo "Not your typical $18...";
}
}
```

Comment: Thanks but how will someone see the Lassoed, Hogtied, and Captured without being registered? And if the user is registered it will then echo a caption depending on their setting?